# Discordjs V13: Add Role from Direct Message

Tags: discord.js

I am trying to assign a role to a user who direct messaging the bot. Although the user was being assigned the role but it throw the error below and shut down my program. I have been researching this issue for few hours but still no luck.

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
```

Error Stack

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
    at GuildMemberRoleManager.get cache [as cache] (C:\Users\josh\Desktop\discord\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\GuildMemberRoleManager.js:36:101)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\josh\Desktop\discord\discordBot.js:46:23)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
TypeError Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
UNHANDLED REJECTION!  Shutting down...
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Here is my code.

```
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client({
  partials: ['CHANNEL'],
  intents: [Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS],
});

client.once('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Ready!`);
});

client.on('messageCreate', async (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;

  if (message.content.startsWith('/test')) {
    const member = await client.guilds.cache
      .get(process.env.DISCORD_GUILD_ID)
      .members.fetch(message.author.id);

    await member.roles.add('123456789012345678');
  }
});

client.login(process.env.DISCORD_TOKEN);
```

Comment: Can we see the full error stack?

Comment: @MrMythical Sure. I have updated the question with the full error stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the lack of `GUILDS` intent. If you look at the source code, [here](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/stable/src/managers/GuildMemberRoleManager.js#L36), it shows that it tries to get the @everyone role from cache, but can't find it since it's not cached (giving `undefined`).

Provide `GUILDS` intent to fix

```js
const client = new Client({
  partials: ['CHANNEL'],
  intents: [Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS],
})
```